# Can I restrict a service account to run BiqQuery queries with dryRun only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I have a service account that is used only for [dry runs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries) to get. I don't need the SA to access actual data in BQ, I wonder if there is way to restrict the SA to execute only dry run queries and not to have access to the data itself.

Comment: It is impossible to restrict the access of data using a service account because for running queries through a service account, it must have access to the tables and underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

The access restriction you are trying to implement is not possible through a service account.

To run a query job, the user must be granted `bigquery.jobs.create` permissions. In order for the query job to complete successfully, the user must also be granted access to the tables or views referenced by the query. The same permissions are required to execute a dry run as stated in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries#permissions_required). So, it is impossible to restrict access using a service account for a dry run query.